# neo4j - Commands withing transaction

Tags: neo4j

Well I am writing server plugin. I want to know what should all commands come with in transaction ?

Like, is it a good programming to begin transaction at the beginning of function and end transaction before return or we should do it in some otherway.

One more thing : Is there any limitations on, what all we can write withing transaction.
Can I write anything in java withing transaction like for loop, while loop , if , else ..

Thanks
Amit Aggarwal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a release < Neo4j 2.0 then only operations that modify the database need to be wrapped in a transaction. In Neo4j 2.0, any operation that accesses the graph needs to be wrapped in a transaction.

You can definitely use loops/branches etc.

Comment: Suppose , My single function contains whole functionality I want to implement then can I start transaction in the beginning and end it in the last ?

Comment: Yes if it needs to be that way